# How can I change the password of MySQL if I forget about it?

Tags: mysql, terminal

If I forget the MySQL's password, how to reset it?

Follow the [mysql reset password](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset).

When I run this command:

```
$ sudo mysql -u root  // refer to the given link '2. Start the mysqld demon process using the --skip-grant-tables option with this command '
```

I got this error in my Terminal:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved it by other way:

1. Step 1,  -> System Preferences -> stop mysql server.
2. Step 2, in Terminal:

   ```
   $ cd /usr/local/mysql/bin/
   ```

   Then type to forbid mysql's verification function :

   ```
   ./mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
   ```

   Then the mysql will re-start, you can in System Preferences -> MySQL to see its running state.
3. Step3:
   Then you type in :

   ```
   ./mysql
   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
   ```

   Then you can reset your mysql's password:

   ```
   SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('your new password');
   ```